# Changing WordPress post status label

Tags: wordpress

I can see how to create a brand new post status but does anyone know how to change the name of the existing drafts post status? I've managed to do it everywhere but on the label which sits next to draft items by default:

[image: Example post status location]

Answer (score 0):

you need to edit the post. Then change the title and save as draft. If the label persists on the admin area make sure you hard refresh the page. `ctrl+shift+R`